# composer ps4 Class not found

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have the following file structure:

- ajon/

  - project/

    - src/

      - subproject1/

        - index.php
        - composer.json
      - subproject2/

        - composer.json

In my composer.json I have:

```
"psr-4": {
   "ajon\\project\\subproject1\\": "src/subproject1/",
   "ajon\\project\\subproject2\\": "src/subproject2/"
}
```

Within subproject1 I have Models/Foo.php which looks like:

```
namespace ajon\project\subproject1\Models;

class Foo { ... }
```

within subproject1/index.php I have:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use ajon\project\subproject1\Models\Foo;
```

I am getting:

```
Class 'ajon\project\subproject1\Models\Foo' not found.
```

- Will composer look for the `namespace ajon\project\subproject1` in the correct folder and then know to look in `Models\Foo` from there?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  It turns out the psr-4 directive is relative to where the composer.json file is.

I set composer.json as such:

```
"psr-4": { "ajon\\project\\subproject1\\": "./" }
```

and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Great job! Could you please also mark your answer as solution? So it's clear it's been resolved successfully. Thank you

Comment: I will,  but it won't let me for another 38 hours.